# Enable/Disable Ribbon Buttons in Word 2007 Addin

Tags: c#, vsto

Currently i am working on a  word Addin, where i have added controls to the ribbon dynamically. Now, I need to catch the dynamic button "btnSubmit" and based on the condition i need to enable/disable the button.

when the document is opened for the first time it should be enabled and Once the Button is clicked it should be disabled.

This should be done on a boolean condition. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,
KSR Prasad

Comment: Hi there, if my answer helped you & it was correct, please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible through RibbonXML using the `getEnabled` event.

Ribbon XML:

```
<button id="button1" onAction="button1_Click" getEnabled="button1_EnabledChanged" />
```

Code:

```
public void button1_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    if (control.Id == "button1")
    {
        // your code
        clicked = true; // a boolean variable
    }
}

public bool button1_EnabledChanged(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    if (control.Id == "button1")
        return !clicked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've already created the button, just create a regional scope WITHEVENTS variable to hold it in, assign it, then react to the click event to disable the button (the button object has an enabled property).

```
Private WithEvents _MyButton As Ribbon.RibbonButton
....
Set _MyButton = {the just created button}
```

then handle the click event

Answer (score 0):

My preference for this type of issue is to use RibbonXml rather than the designer.

A really simple option would be have a Dictionary which you can then store in the ribbon callback class. If you wanted a nicer option, VSTO Contrib (http://vstocontrib.codeplex.com/) allows you to create a 'viewmodel' per document quite easily, then you simply can bind the button enabled to a property on the viewmodel.

More info on ribbon xml: http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-ribbon-designer-in-depth
More info on vsto contrib and how it can help you: http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-contrib/ribbon-factory

Cheers,
Jake